# How to configure LAN segments in CentOS 7 clients?

Tags: networking, centos, vmware-workstation, centos-7

I created a set of VMs and I want for them to share a communication channel (or more) between them. So I added, aside the NAT interface to connect to the internet, a LAN Segment interface or two.
My VMs are running CentOS 7 (text only), and now I'm a bit at a loss on how to configure this channel of communication. The ideal would be for them to mantain DHCP for NAT but static IP for the segments.
Can anyone give me some guidance? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LAN Segments are used to isolate the VM from your normal network. If you want 2 VMs to communicate between them you need to place them on the same LAN Segment. 
If you want to have a fully functional network and have NAT, DHCP, DNS, I suggest to install a router like pfsense, have one network set as WAN (your physical adapter or network that you use) and set the LAN as part of the LAN Segment. Place the other 2 CentOS machines on the same LAN Segment and allow them to use DHCP.

You should have something like (example) 10.0.0.10 on WAN and 192.168.1.x for the LAN Segment. This is how I use it in my lab.

Comment: Ok, thank you, going to try it out like that. But the IP won't be necessarelly dynamic through DHCP?

Comment: It depends how you configure your DHCP Server that will lease IP addresses for that LAN Segment. For instance, in my case, I use pfsense to lease IPs. If you want the CentOS machines to have a static IP, place them on the same subnet (LAN Segment) like 192.168.1.x and they should be able to talk to each other. I also suggest to take the static addresses out of DHCP pool. If you still have questions, please, feel free to ask.